# DataGrid in Extender with Complex Header not binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Working on a display for lists of test data. The datagrid inside my ListBox.ItemTemplate does not bind to the list item data. As I am still just learning this, I am looking for a little insight.

The Model has the basic properties of

```cs
public class Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string TestName { get; }
  public bool TestResult { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<DataPair> TestData { get; } = null;
  public bool IsOverride { get; set; } = false;
  public string Note { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public ObservableCollection<Result> SubTestResults { get; }=null;
  //Methods and constructors
}
```

The View Model associated with the main DockPanel is:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel
  {

    public ObservableCollection<Result> ResultData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Result>();
    public ObservableCollection<Result> PerscriptionData { get => ResultData.First().SubTestResults; } //Test method
    //Non relevant methods removed for clairity
  }
```

And finally The main panel XAML (there is no significant codebehind)

```xml
<DockPanel x:Class="MQTransferValidation.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MQTransferValidation.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"  LastChildFill="True">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="FailImage" UriSource="../Images/RedX.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="PassImage" UriSource="../Images/GreenCheck.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="OverrideImage" UriSource="../Images/YellowCheck.png"/>
       <!--Removed Image Style definition to reduce material>

    </DockPanel.Resources>

    <!--Removed code from other objects in dock panel to reduce length-->

    <ListBox Name="mainPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding PerscriptionData}" >
          <!--ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AtomicResultTemplate}"-->
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="MQTransferValidation.Model.Result" >
            <Expander >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="30" Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource ImageStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding TestName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" Height="30" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Override" IsEnabled="False" Height="30" Width="150"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Eclispe Data" Binding="{Binding EclipseData}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mosaiq Data" Binding="{Binding MosaiqData}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

While I do not plan on the final product having all of this in a single file, during my learning/debugging I wanted to try and eliminate other errors. Where Am i going wrong with the binding command for my DataGrid?

Comment: Are you sure that the TestData has values? I don't see any issues other than that. (Assuming that EclipseData and MosaiqData are present inside DataPair class)

Comment: Yea, I actually have a message box showing me that the data is there before it pops up the window

Comment: Do you set `DataContext` anywhere?

Comment: In my learning, I found out that Properties and public Data are not the same in WPF. Basically it was looking for a property EclipseData but my definition was only public string EclipseData. once I added the property syntax it worked fine.